# ERROR error parsing environment "maas": no public ssh keys found..is it a bug

Tags: juju, maas

no matter what i do i get

ERROR error parsing environment "maas": no public ssh keys found

My environments.yaml file. (authorized key added as per another ask, ubuntu help example)

juju: environments *(dimitern edit: what is this line for?)*

```
environments:
  maas:
        type: maas
        maas-server: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/MAAS/'
        maas-oauth: ' WVNY2RCzVUKSpur3xW:pEpz9QUcLmzV5Kqq3G:mLyWusVjbSAMPLE'
        admin-secret: 'SAMPLE'
        bootstrap-addresses-delay: 10
        bootstrap-retry-delay: 5
        bootstrap-timeout: 3600
        authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `authorized-keys-path` as juju will automatically discover your `~/.ssh/*` keys and try to use them.

See `juju help authorized-keys` for more information how to manage these in an environment.

Also you don't need to specify `admin-secret`, it will be auto-generated when bootstrapping. The `bootstrap-addresses-delay` and `bootstrap-retry-delay` rarely need to be overridden in `environments.yaml` at all (and you're using the defaults anyway, so I'd skip them), just `bootstrap-timeout`.

Comment: nothing is happening still getting the same error

Comment: What version of Juju are you using (run `juju version`) ? You might need to upgrade to a more recent version, as lots of bugs were fixed between 16 May and now.